# Dart: Object is giving output only once even when called multiple times

Tags: flutter, class, dart, object, constructor

Hi I am trying to print value of 'a' property of x object but I only get output once.

```
void main() {
  var x = Test("Boy");
  x;
  x;
  x;
  x;
  x;
  x;
}

class Test {
  Test(var b) {
    this.a = b;
    print(a);
  }
  var a;
}
```

Output:

```
Boy
```

Comment: Your only print statement is in the constructor and you only call the constructor once (`Test('Boy')`). All the `x;x;x;x;` rows do nothing. What were you expecting them to do instead?

Comment: I've written detailed explanation. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In constructor you call `print` function

```
    Test(var b) {
    this.a = b;
    print(a);
  }
```

Therefore - print is called whenever the **constructor** called.
Here you calling instance (variable), not constructor

```
  x;
  x;
  x;
  x;
  x;
  x;
```

It is printed once because you call **constructor** only once

```
var x = Test("Boy");
```

So if you try calling constructor multiple times then it will print multiple times

```
var x = Test("Boy");
var y = Test("Boy");
var z = Test("Boy");
```

Answer (score 0):

calling the constructor only when you create a new object.
Like

```
var x1 = Test("Boy1");
var x2 = Test("Boy2");
```